# How to set a column in tensor to 0s?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a tensor that looks like:

```
[[4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [4, 125, 6],
 [72, 81, 91]]
```

and I want all the values in the first and last column to be 0s, so the result would look something like:

```
[[0, 5, 0],
 [0, 8, 0],
 [0, 125, 0],
 [0, 81, 0]]
```

What's the simplest and most efficient way to do this in tensorflow (version 1.4)?

I tried using tf.boolean_mask, but my version of tf doesn't support the axis parameter and it seemed to remove the columns rather than zero them out, anyway.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

***EDIT:***
The input tensor could have any number of columns > 3, and the output tensor will be that tensor with exactly two (specified) columns "zeroed" out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.one_hot()` to create a mask tensor with ones in the second column and then do element-wise multiplication with the tensor you want second column from:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[4, 5, 6],
                      [7, 8, 9],
                      [4, 125, 6],
                      [72, 81, 91]], dtype=tf.float32)

col_to_zero = [0, 2] # <-- column numbers you want to be zeroed out
tnsr_shape = tf.shape(tensor)
mask = [tf.one_hot(col_num*tf.ones((tnsr_shape[0], ), dtype=tf.int32), tnsr_shape[-1])
        for col_num in col_to_zero]
mask = tf.reduce_sum(mask, axis=0)
mask = tf.cast(tf.logical_not(tf.cast(mask, tf.bool)), tf.float32)

result = tensor * mask

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(result.eval())
# [[  0.   5.   0.]
#  [  0.   8.   0.]
#  [  0. 125.   0.]
#  [  0.  81.   0.]]
```

`col_to_zero` is a list of column numbers you want to be zeroed out. For example, setting `col_to_zero = [1, 2]` will keep only the first column and zero all others in your example.

Comment: Thank you! However, I realize my example was a bit too specific; the input tensor could have any number of columns > 3, and the output tensor will be that tensor with exactly two columns "zeroed" out. Could you help with how to do that? (edited the question to reflect this new constraint)

Comment: Yes, sure, but I’ll do it tomorrow. It’s past midnight in my place.

Comment: @Kevin consider accepting my answer if it answers your question.